# Error when run android app - ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem when I run the app... I want to test the location with GPS in my android phone but I can`t, ... it´s only that.

this is my ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node  : v7.0.0
    npm   : 3.10.8
    OS    : macOS Sierra
    Xcode : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

l

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

This is the error:

Error:

```
./src/app/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app'
resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app'
  using description file: /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    using description file: /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.json doesn't exist
      as directory
        /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
[/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory]
[/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts]
[/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js]
[/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.json]
[/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory]
 @ ./src/app/main.ts 2:0-60
    at new BuildError (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at callback (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:121:28)
    at emitRecords.err (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:269:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:375:38)
    at emitAssets.err (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:262:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:222:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (/Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:365:9)
```

app.module.ts, I want to test the location but I can`t, there is the library for location and the service to call the webservice

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TestPage } from '../pages/test/test';

import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

import { MessageServiceProvider } from '../providers/message-service/message-service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TestPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TestPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    MessageServiceProvider,
    Geolocation
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

So, I need your help ... what is the wrong? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Similiar issue is reported in [angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18380). Please try the following steps

1. Upgrade the angular CLI to latest version `npm install @angular/cli` and take the build
2. if it's still not working run `npm i enhanced-resolve@3.3.0`

Comment: same error: Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/eliascanaza/Documents/www/ionic/yofood/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

It says that **Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' **

1.check your main.ts file it should have `import { AppModule } from './app.module';` not something like app.module.ngfactory.

2.Also make sure your app works without errors first using `Ionic Serve` and check console for any app specific errors.